# How to make List from Numpy Matrix in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, numpy

I using the dot() function from numpy to multiply a matrix of 3x3 with a numpy.array of 1x3. The output is for example this:

[[ 0.16666667  0.66666667  0.16666667]]

which is of type:

```
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
```

how can I convert this to a list. Because I know the result will always be a matrix of 1x3 so it should be coverted to a list because I need to be able to loop through it later for calculation the pearson distance of two of those lists.

**So to summarize: how can I make a list from this matrix?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

May not be the optimal way to do this but the following works:

```
a = numpy.matrix([[ 0.16666667, 0.66666667, 0.16666667]])
list(numpy.array(a).reshape(-1,))
```

or

```
numpy.array(a).reshape(-1,).tolist()
```

or

```
numpy.array(a)[0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the [tolist()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.tolist.html) method on the matrix object :

```
>>> import numpy
>>> m = numpy.matrix([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(m)
<class 'numpy.core.defmatrix.matrix'>
>>> m.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: the problem is that the whole matrix then becomes 1 element fo a list with 1 element. Like: [[0.16666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]]. I need every value to be an element of a new list of length 3. How can i do that?

Comment: Same as other comments said: numpy.array(a).reshape(-1,).tolist() or use ravel()

Answer (score 15):

If `a` is your matrix, try

```
a.ravel().tolist()
```

but you don't need to turn it into a list to iterate over it.

Comment: I know I don't need that to iterate over it, but a whole class is written to handle lists, so it is easier if I make a list of it then to change the whole class. However, with your solution I too get a list with 1 element that is the matrix instead of a list with 3 elements. How can i make the latter? any ideas?

Comment: @Javaaaa: You get a list with a single item that is a list itself.  Simply use `[0]` to retrieve that single item.

Comment: `ravel()` is redundant: `b.tolist() == b.ravel().tolist()` >>> `True`

Comment: @Martin: No, it's only redundant if your matrix only has a single line in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Another way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.matrix([1,2,3])
>>> np.array(m).flatten().tolist()
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

why not simple:

```
list(a.flat)
```

for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[ 0.16666667, 0.66666667, 0.16666667]])
>>> a
matrix([[ 0.16666667,  0.66666667,  0.16666667]])
>>> a.flat
<numpy.flatiter object at 0x0000000002DE8CC0>
>>> a.flat.tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.flatiter' object has no attribute 'tolist'
>>> list(a.flat)
[0.16666666999999999, 0.66666667000000002, 0.16666666999999999]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = numpy.matrix([[ 0.16666667, 0.66666667, 0.16666667]])
a = numpy.array(m)[0]

for i in a:
    print i
```

results in

```
0.16666667
0.66666667
0.16666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplistic approach. It works with 1D arrays, do not know with higher dimensions.

```
import mumpy as np         # to create a numpy array example
a = np.array([1,2.5,3])    # your 1D numpy array
b = [i for i in a]        # your list out of the original numpy array
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `getA1()` can do the job.
From the documentation:

> getA1()
>
> Return self as a flattened ndarray.
>
> Equivalent to np.asarray(x).ravel()

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getA1.html

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a way to convert numpy matrices to typical 2D lists.

For a numpy matrix m:

```
my_2d_list = map(list, list(m.A))
```

If you just want a one dimensional list from a 1 x n matrix m:

```
my_1d_list = list(list(m.A)[0])
```

Comment: As shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183572/901925 `tolist()` on a 2d array (e.g. matrix) produces a nested list.  I assume that's what you are calling a 'typical 2D list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4]])
b = map(float, a.transpose())
```

This code snippet will apply the built-in function "float" - which converts something to a floating point number - to every element of *a*. Since the first element of *a* is an array itself, it has to be transposed, so that every number becomes an element of *a* itself. a.transpose() is equivalent to np.matrix([[1],[2],[3],[4]]) in this example.

Comment: Please try to explain your answer in a few words even if your code is working